# Where to set color on an IBDesignableTextField

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a question on where it is recommended to set the color of a `UITextField` that I have subclassed. Here is some code.

```
@IBDesignable
class TextField: UITextField {

     //var inset is not important for this question. 
     @IBInspectable var inset: CGFloat = 10

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
           //tried setting color here, didn't show up in storyboard
      } 

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
          //tried setting color here, didn't show up in storyboard
     }

     override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
          super.drawRect(rect)
          //tried setting color here, didn't show up in storyboard
     }

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
         self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
         //HERE IT WORKS!!!
         return CGRectInset(bounds, inset, inset)
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
         return textRectForBounds(bounds)
    }
}
```

So, what I am basically trying to do is write a subclass of `UITextField` that sets the background color of a text field (among other things in the future) that shows up in the storyboard. The only place that I could get it to work is on the `textRectForBounds:` function that I have to set padding for the text. My question is, where is it recommended to set the background color of a `UITextField` and have that change show up in storyboard? Thanks.

Comment: Try setting it in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`.

Comment: @Caleb that works in the storyboard, but then when I run the app in simulator, the changed don't show up.

Comment: Try... [willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)

Comment: @andrewbuilder this is not a tableView... subclassing `UITextField` won't have that method

Comment: @AnthonyDito of course! See you've got it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I got this to work is adding these methods...

```
#if !TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self._setup()
}
#endif

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    self._setup()
}

func _setup() {
    //do all the setup here to make the appearance show up in Interface builder and app.
}
```